# iOS Did URL Schemes has default value when i haven't define the url schemes?

Tags: ios, xcode, url, nsurl, uiapplication

I know i should call below function to check if app installed :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"customURLSchemes://"]]
```

However, i made an application long time ago but have not define "URL Schemes", and now i would like to make another app and check if user has installed my app, i tried

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app://myAppName"]]  
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app://com.company.appid"]]  
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myAppName://"]]  
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"com.company.appid://"]]
```

and above all returned FALSE, how can i check my app installed ?

Comment: i tried update my old app and define url schemes, but when my new app call

Answer (score 1):

If your old app doesn't have an explicit custom URL scheme then there is no way to check if the app is installed.

Submit an update to the app and specify an URL scheme.

Comment: I tried update my old app and define url Schemes as @"fp.ht", and called   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fp.ht://"]]  and it still returned FALSE...

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think a URL scheme can have a period.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. iOS apps are sandboxed. You can't raise some sort of periscope and look outside your sandbox; that would be a violation of security / privacy.